# Change values depending of others values generated automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have developed a web app to manage the bonuses of a company.

It has two pages, the first one to fill a form and declare a "no-bonus" reason and the second one to consult who will be entitled to a bonus at the end of the month.

The main rule is that for two no-bonus reasons filled in for one person, the bonus will not be paid. Each employee's counter is reset to zero each month.

So I was able to make the application with the form without any problems. I was also able to upload the different "no-bonus" in the consultation page. However, I would like to add a table with the list of employees, the number of "no-bonus" of the month and if they are entitled to their bonus or not.

To do this, I made a specific tab in my Google Sheets with a column for "employee", one for the number of "no-bonus" (with a CountIfs formula) and one to know if the bonus is granted or not. I added the onEdit(e) function in my code to be able to display "No" if the number of "no-bonus" is greater than 1 and "Yes" in the opposite case.

The problem I have is that my onEdit(e) acts when I make a modification in a cell of the no-bonus column. It does not act when I fill in the form. And I don't see how to counter this.

Here is the code of my onEdit(e) function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   var ss = e.source;
   var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var cell = e.range;

  if (activeSheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && cell.getColumn() == 2 && cell.getRow() > 1) {
     var choice1 = cell.getValue();
     if (choice1 > 1){
       cell.offset(0,1).clearDataValidations()
       cell.offset(0,1).setValue("No");
     }
     else{
       cell.offset(0,1).clearDataValidations()
       cell.offset(0,1).setValue("Yes");
     }
   }
 }
```

Here is the link of the Sheets in question: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17IWMRXAmxpm6NpZ6T-pVWE3ewZRENoqQyl2csb2GoiQ/edit?usp=sharing)

For those who don't want to access the link, here is a screenshot of the tab where the fromulaire requests are saved :

[image]

And here is the table where the onEdit(e) function is used:

[image]

Sorry for my English, it is quite average. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: onEdit on respond to user edits not edits caused by formulas or other scripts

Comment: Is there a way around this problem by any chance?

Comment: It is not a problem.  It's just the way it works.